# one quantitative one qualitative bivariate Analysis

Tags: r, statistics, categorical-data, stat, quantitative

I'm level -1000 in statistics and I need an expert help

in my project, I have data set with 3 variables one categorical and 2 are quantitative and I'm supposed to Conduct a bivariate analysis with the purpose to understand the factors that may contribute to the identification of the categorical variable in the considered data set.

the question is can I use simple or multiaple regression ?
if the answer is yes, can you show me how to do it?
and if it's no, what should I use instead? and how to interpret?

Comment: Can you share at least some data? You can use [`dput()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput). Have you tried to use any model?. I think you might consider posting your question in [crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) since it is a doubt about statistics and not so much about code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.